# XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc100000, needed 0xc180000)

Tags: perl, mismatch

I have tried over and over to make this work.
I've combed this site and others and see many folks have run into this same issue but I just don't see how to resolve it.
I've successfully installed perl 5.20 on this system but am told I need to upgrade to 5.30 for security reasons.
My installation almost couldn't be simpler.
I'm installing perl 5.30.3 on RHEL 4 Nahant.
My Configure looks like this:

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/home/rg8239/perl -Dcc=gcc
```

The perl works fine.  Here's the "perl -V" output:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 30 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux
    osvers=2.6.9-34.elsmp
    archname=x86_64-linux
    uname='linux gcp4al16 2.6.9-34.elsmp #1 smp fri feb 24 16:56:28 est 2006 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Dprefix=/home/rg8239/perl -Dcc=gcc'
    hint=recommended
    useposix=true
    d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=undef
    usemultiplicity=undef
    use64bitint=define
    use64bitall=define
    uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n
    default_inc_excludes_dot=define
    bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc'
    ccflags ='-fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
    optimize='-O2'
    cppflags='-fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion=''
    gccversion='3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)'
    gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4
    longsize=8
    ptrsize=8
    doublesize=8
    byteorder=12345678
    doublekind=3
    d_longlong=define
    longlongsize=8
    d_longdbl=define
    longdblsize=16
    longdblkind=3
    ivtype='long'
    ivsize=8
    nvtype='double'
    nvsize=8
    Off_t='off_t'
    lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8
    prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc'
    ldflags =' -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib /lib64 /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64
    libs=-lpthread -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    libc=libc-2.3.4.so
    so=so
    useshrplib=false
    libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version='2.3.4'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs
    dlext=so
    d_dlsymun=undef
    ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC'
    lddlflags='-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options:
    HAS_TIMES
    PERLIO_LAYERS
    PERL_COPY_ON_WRITE
    PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
    PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
    PERL_OP_PARENT
    PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
    USE_64_BIT_ALL
    USE_64_BIT_INT
    USE_LARGE_FILES
    USE_LOCALE
    USE_LOCALE_COLLATE
    USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
    USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC
    USE_LOCALE_TIME
    USE_PERLIO
    USE_PERL_ATOF
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Jun 18 2020 02:25:18
  @INC:
    /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux
    /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3
    /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux
    /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3
```

Now I try to install my first module, List::MoreUtils
It fails with :

```
XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc100000, needed 0xc180000)
```

Here's the cpan install output (redundant lines and most comments omitted):

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/home/rg8239/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 19 Jun 2020 20:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'List::MoreUtils'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz ok
/bin/tar: Read 6144 bytes from -
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking whether pureperl is required... no
Checking for cc... gcc
Checking for cc... (cached) gcc
Checking whether perlapi is accessible... Warning: prerequisite Exporter::Tiny 0.038 not found.
Warning: prerequisite List::MoreUtils::XS 0.426 not found.
yes
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for List::MoreUtils
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----    REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz   ----
    Exporter::Tiny [requires]
    List::MoreUtils::XS [requires]
    Test::LeakTrace [build_requires]
Running install for module 'Exporter::Tiny'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz ok
/bin/tar: Read 1536 bytes from -
Configuring T/TO/TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Exporter::Tiny
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for T/TO/TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----   TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz  ----
    Test::Fatal [build_requires,optional]
    Test::Warnings [build_requires,optional]
cp lib/Exporter/Tiny.pm blib/lib/Exporter/Tiny.pm
cp lib/Exporter/Shiny.pm blib/lib/Exporter/Shiny.pm
cp lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Etc.pod blib/lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Etc.pod
cp lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Importing.pod blib/lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Importing.pod
cp lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/QuickStart.pod blib/lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/QuickStart.pod
cp lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Exporting.pod blib/lib/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Exporting.pod
Manifying 6 pod documents
  TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# Perl 5.030003
t/01basic.t .............. ok
t/02renaming.t ........... ok
t/03generators.t ......... ok
t/04into.t ............... ok
t/05shiny.t .............. ok
t/06notwant.t ............ ok
t/07regexp.t ............. ok
t/08tags.t ............... ok
t/09warnings.t ........... skipped: test requires Test::Warnings and Test::Fatal
t/10no.t ................. ok
t/11noncode.t ............ ok
t/12noncodegenerators.t .. ok
t/13doesntexist.t ........ ok
All tests successful.
Files=13, Tests=64,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.03 sys +  1.21 cusr  0.20 csys =  1.51 CPU)
Result: PASS
  TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install for TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
Manifying 6 pod documents
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Shiny.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Tiny.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Exporting.pod
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/QuickStart.pod
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Etc.pod
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Exporter/Tiny/Manual/Importing.pod
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Tiny::Manual::Exporting.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Tiny::Manual::Etc.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Tiny.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Tiny::Manual::QuickStart.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Shiny.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Exporter::Tiny::Manual::Importing.3
Appending installation info to /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
  TOBYINK/Exporter-Tiny-1.002002.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
Running install for module 'Test::Warnings'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz ok
/bin/tar: Read 2048 bytes from -
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::Warnings
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
cp lib/Test/Warnings.pm blib/lib/Test/Warnings.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# 
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
# REST OF COMMENTS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
#
t/00-report-prereqs.t ................. ok
t/01-basic.t .......................... ok
t/02-done_testing.t ................... ok
t/03-subtest.t ........................ ok
t/04-no-tests.t ....................... ok
t/05-no-end-block.t ................... ok
t/06-skip-all.t ....................... skipped: Need Does::Not::Exist::627351373042078 to continue!
t/07-no_plan.t ........................ ok
t/08-use-if.t ......................... ok
t/09-warnings-contents.t .............. ok
t/10-no-done_testing.t ................ ok
t/11-double-use.t ..................... ok
t/12-no-newline.t ..................... ok
t/13-propagate-warnings.t ............. ok
t/14-propagate-subname.t .............. ok
t/15-propagate-default.t .............. ok
t/16-propagate-ignore.t ............... ok
t/17-propagate-subname-colons.t ....... ok
t/18-propagate-subname-package.t ...... ok
t/19-propagate-nonexistent-subname.t .. ok
t/20-propagate-stub.t ................. ok
t/21-fail-on-warning.t ................ ok
t/22-warnings-bareword.t .............. ok
t/23-report-warnings.t ................ ok
t/zzz-check-breaks.t .................. ok
All tests successful.
Files=25, Tests=81,  4 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr  0.04 sys +  3.00 cusr  0.53 csys =  3.70 CPU)
Result: PASS
  ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install for ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Test/Warnings.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Test::Warnings.3
Appending installation info to /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
  ETHER/Test-Warnings-0.030.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
Running install for module 'Test::Fatal'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz ok
Configuring R/RJ/RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite Try::Tiny 0.07 not found.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::Fatal
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz       ----
    Try::Tiny [requires]
Running install for module 'Try::Tiny'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz ok
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Try::Tiny
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
cp lib/Try/Tiny.pm blib/lib/Try/Tiny.pm 
Manifying 1 pod document
  ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# 
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
# 
# === Configure Requires ===
# 
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.34
# 
# REST OF COMMENTS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
#
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... ok
t/basic.t ...................... ok
t/context.t .................... ok
t/erroneous_usage.t ............ ok
t/finally.t .................... ok
t/given_when.t ................. skipped: Tests skipped on perl 5.27.7+, pending resolution of smartmatch changes
t/global_destruction_forked.t .. ok
t/global_destruction_load.t .... skipped: Capture::Tiny 0.12 required
t/named.t ...................... ok
t/when.t ....................... skipped: Tests skipped on perl 5.27.7+, pending resolution of smartmatch changes
t/zzz-check-breaks.t ........... ok
All tests successful. 
Files=11, Tests=97,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.03 sys +  1.43 cusr  0.20 csys =  1.72 CPU)
Result: PASS         
  ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install for ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Try/Tiny.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Try::Tiny.3
Appending installation info to /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
  ETHER/Try-Tiny-0.30.tar.gz   
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK   
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz  
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/Test-Fatal-0.014-2
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
cp lib/Test/Fatal.pm blib/lib/Test/Fatal.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# 
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
#     
# REST OF COMMENTS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
#
t/00-report-prereqs.t .. ok
t/basic.t .............. ok
t/like-exception.t ..... ok
t/todo.t ............... ok
All tests successful.
Files=4, Tests=16,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.02 sys +  0.68 cusr  0.10 csys =  0.85 CPU)
Result: PASS
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install for RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/Test/Fatal.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Test::Fatal.3
Appending installation info to /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
  RJBS/Test-Fatal-0.014.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
Running install for module 'List::MoreUtils::XS'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz ok
/bin/tar: Read 7680 bytes from -
Configuring R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking whether pureperl is required... no
Checking for cc... gcc
Checking for cc... (cached) gcc
Checking whether perlapi is accessible... yes
Checking for stdlib.h... yes
Checking for stdarg.h... yes
Checking for string.h... yes
Checking for float.h... yes 
Checking for assert.h... yes
Checking for ctype.h... yes  
Checking for errno.h... yes  
Checking for limits.h... yes 
Checking for locale.h... yes
Checking for math.h... yes   
Checking for setjmp.h... yes
Checking for signal.h... yes
Checking for stddef.h... yes
Checking for stdio.h... yes   
Checking for time.h... yes
Checking for sys/types.h... yes
Checking for sys/stat.h... yes
Checking for memory.h... yes
Checking for strings.h... yes
Checking for inttypes.h... yes
Checking for stdint.h... yes
Checking for unistd.h... yes 
Checking for time.h... (cached) yes
Checking for sys/time.h... yes
Checking for time... yes     
Checking for size_t... yes   
Checking for ssize_t... yes  
Checking for builtin expect... no
Checking for statement expression feature... no
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for List::MoreUtils::XS
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz  ----
    Test::LeakTrace [build_requires,optional]
cp lib/List/MoreUtils/XS.pm blib/lib/List/MoreUtils/XS.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for XS ()
chmod 644 "XS.bs"
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- XS.bs blib/arch/auto/List/MoreUtils/XS/XS.bs 644
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/ExtUtils/typemap
'  XS.xs > XS.xsc
mv XS.xsc XS.c 
gcc -c  -I. -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.428\" -DX
S_VERSION=\"0.428\" -fPIC "-I/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/CORE"   XS.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/List/MoreUtils/XS/XS.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib  XS.o  -o blib/arch/auto/List/MoreUtils/XS/XS.so  \
      \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/List/MoreUtils/XS/XS.so
Manifying 1 pod document 
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- XS.bs blib/arch/auto/List/MoreUtils/XS/XS.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/xs/*.t xt/*.t
XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc100000, needed 0xc180000)
t/xs/after.t ................
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
No subtests run
XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc100000, needed 0xc180000)
t/xs/after_incl.t ...........
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
No subtests run
XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc100000, needed 0xc180000)
t/xs/all.t ..................
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
No subtests run

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/xs/after.t              (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 1
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xs/after_incl.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 1
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xs/all.t                (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 1
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output

t/xs/zip6.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 1
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=59, Tests=0,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.21 usr  0.13 sys +  0.90 cusr  0.34 csys =  1.58 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 59/59 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 1
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz
Running install for module 'Test::LeakTrace'
Checksum for /home/rg8239/.cpan/sources/authors/id/L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz ok
Configuring L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::LeakTrace
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
  /home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace/Script.pm blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace/Script.pm
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace.pm blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace.pm
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace/JA.pod blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace/JA.pod
Running Mkbootstrap for LeakTrace ()
chmod 644 "LeakTrace.bs"
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LeakTrace.bs blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrac
e.bs 644
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-Iinc" "/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/ExtUtils
/typemap'  LeakTrace.xs > LeakTrace.xsc
mv LeakTrace.xsc LeakTrace.c
gcc -c   -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.16\" -DXS_VE
RSION=\"0.16\" -fPIC "-I/home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/CORE"   LeakTrace.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrace.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib  LeakTrace.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrace.so  \
      \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrace.so
Manifying 3 pod documents
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LeakTrace.bs blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrac
e.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
# Testing Test::LeakTrace/0.16
t/00_compile.t ..... ok
t/01_info.t ........ ok   
t/02_refs.t ........ ok 
t/03_count.t ....... ok 
t/04_test_funcs.t .. ok   
t/05_script.t ...... ok 
t/06_threads.t ..... skipped: require threads
t/07_eval.t ........ ok
t/08_leaktrace.t ... ok
t/09_info_more.t ... ok
t/10_bad_use.t ..... ok
t/11_logfp.t ....... ok
t/12_padstale.t .... ok 
t/13_do.t .......... ok
All tests successful.
Files=14, Tests=126,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.10 usr  0.04 sys +  2.10 cusr  0.33 csys =  2.57 CPU)
Result: PASS 
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install for LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
"/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LeakTrace.bs blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrac
e.bs 644
Manifying 3 pod documents
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrace.so
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/Test/LeakTrace.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/Test/LeakTrace/Script.pm
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/Test/LeakTrace/JA.pod
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Test::LeakTrace.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Test::LeakTrace::Script.3
Installing /home/rg8239/perl/man/man3/Test::LeakTrace::JA.3
Appending installation info to /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.16.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/List-MoreUtils-0.428-4
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'List::MoreUtils::XS => 0.426' for 'REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz' failed when processing 'REHSACK/List-
MoreUtils-XS-0.428.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/List/MoreUtils.pm blib/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm
cp lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm blib/lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm
cp lib/List/MoreUtils/Contributing.pod blib/lib/List/MoreUtils/Contributing.pod
Manifying 3 pod documents
  REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK 
Running make test for REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/rg8239/perl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; tes
t_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/pureperl/*.t t/xs/*.t xt/*.t
t/pureperl/after.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/after_incl.t ........... ok
t/pureperl/all.t .................. ok
t/pureperl/all_u.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/any.t .................. ok
t/pureperl/any_u.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/apply.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/arrayify.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/before.t ............... ok
t/pureperl/before_incl.t .......... ok
t/pureperl/binsert.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/bremove.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/bsearch.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/bsearchidx.t ........... ok
t/pureperl/duplicates.t ........... ok
t/pureperl/each_array.t ........... ok
t/pureperl/equal_range.t .......... ok
t/pureperl/false.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/firstidx.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/firstres.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/firstval.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/frequency.t ............ ok
t/pureperl/Import.t ............... ok
t/pureperl/indexes.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/insert_after.t ......... ok
t/pureperl/insert_after_string.t .. ok
t/pureperl/lastidx.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/lastres.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/lastval.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/listcmp.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/lower_bound.t .......... ok
t/pureperl/mesh.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/minmax.t ............... ok
t/pureperl/minmaxstr.t ............ ok
t/pureperl/mode.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/natatime.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/none.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/none_u.t ............... ok
t/pureperl/notall.t ............... ok
t/pureperl/notall_u.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/occurrences.t .......... ok
t/pureperl/one.t .................. ok
t/pureperl/one_u.t ................ ok
t/pureperl/onlyidx.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/onlyres.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/onlyval.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/pairwise.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/part.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/qsort.t ................ skipped: It's insane to use a pure-perl qsort
t/pureperl/reduce_0.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/reduce_1.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/reduce_u.t ............. ok
t/pureperl/samples.t .............. ok
t/pureperl/singleton.t ............ ok
t/pureperl/true.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/uniq.t ................. ok
t/pureperl/upper_bound.t .......... ok
t/pureperl/XS.t ................... ok
t/pureperl/zip6.t ................. ok
Can't locate List/MoreUtils/XS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the List::MoreUtils::XS module) (@INC contains: /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/List-MoreUtils-0.428-4/blib/lib /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/List-MoreUtils-0.428-4/blib/arch /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.
30.3/x86_64-linux /home/rg8239/perl/lib/site_perl/5.30.3 /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3/x86_64-linux /home/rg8239/perl/lib/5.30.3 .) a
t /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/List-MoreUtils-0.428-4/blib/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/rg8239/.cpan/build/List-MoreUtils-0.428-4/blib/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at t/xs/after.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/xs/after.t line 7.
t/xs/after.t ...................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
```

I really need some expert guidance here!
Thanks very much, Rick

Comment: `Can't locate List/MoreUtils/XS.pm in @INC`. Try to install `List::MoreUtils::XS` first?

Comment: Do you have any PERL* environment variables set? Usually this indicates that perl is trying to load a library it found in another perl's installation.

Comment: Nothing; no PERL5LIB or LD_LIBRARY_PATH or anything like that

Comment: I had tried List::MoreUtils::XS.  No luck